# How can I create a child process from a command line input

Tags: c, fork, child-process

If I input this command onto a Linux terminal, and lets say ./loop is a C program that I've compiled. (./loop is just a program that prints 'hello world' for n amount of times)

```
$time ./loop 8
```

I'm looking to take this command line input of `./loop 8`, and pass the calling of it to a new child process instead of letting the original process run it. And hence the process `time` would have to wait for the termination of the child process (ie. ./loop).

I'm still very new to the entirity of fork() and exec() (and C language programming as well :b) so was wondering how could I take the command line argument and start the command as a new child process?

***EDIT***: is this the possible solution?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t pid = fork()
    if (pid < 0)
    {
      return -1;
    }
    else if(pid = 0 ){
      printf("i am a child process, with pid: %d\n", (int)getpid());
      int execvp(char *argv[0], char *argv[1]);
      exit(0);
    }
    else{
      printf("i am parent ");
      int status ;
      pid_t child_pid;
      child_pid = wait4(pid, &status, 0)
//print the exit statment 
//prirnt the exit stats (ie. run time, etc.)
      
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your aim in the end? You can just use `execve` to execute a program based on an argv-style argument vector (which is what you get as input to your C program anyway).

Comment: What I'm looking to do is these child process return their running time, and other stats to the "main program" which would then print it out. I used "time" here as an example. Its a requirement of mine to call new process hence.  @AKX

Comment: How would the child process "return a running time and other stats"? (`time` is easy; it can just measure how much time it took for the process to run, and ask the OS for other bookkeeping information if it needs to.) You will need to think of the method with which you want the processes to communicate with each other.

Comment: sorry, I didnt specify it clearly. Id be using wait4() to do so

Comment: Well, alright – then you'd fork(), execve() in the child (so it's replaced by the program-to-be-measured), and use wait4() in the parent on the forked child's pid.

Comment: Is `time` the shell builtin, a utility like `/usr/bin/time`, or a command of your own that you are asking about?

Comment: @WilliamPursell its the shell built in. But im just using that as a "placeholder" for a program I need to work on.

Comment: @AKX, its just the intricacies of forwarding the command and its concerning arguments that Im not too sure about, hence wanted to clarify on that

Comment: Well, what you posted isn't valid C to begin with, so no, that's not the solution. But you're pretty close there – if you consider `./myprog /bin/cat hello`, then `argv[1]` is `/bin/cat`, the program you want to run, so just `argv + 1` gets you a "slice" of `argv` that starts where you want . . .

Comment: Ahh, right right, thanks for this! But apart from the indexing, the passing of the arguments to call a new child is alright ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you're looking for something like this (which doesn't do anything with the `rusage` yet, but feel free to). (Also, there are no bounds checks. Be careful.)

The important thing to understand is that the child process *becomes* the process executed by `execvp` and doesn't start a new child of its own.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid < 0) {
    perror("fork failed");
    return 1;
  } else if (pid == 0) {
    printf("i am a child process, with pid: %d\n", (int)getpid());
    execvp(argv[1], argv + 1);
    // This can only be reached if execvp returns (i.e. fails to exec)
    perror("execvp failed");
    exit(123);
  }
  printf("i am parent of %d\n", pid);
  int status; 
  struct rusage ru;
  pid_t child_pid = wait4(pid, &status, 0, &ru);
  if(child_pid < 0) {
    perror("wait4 failed");
  } else {
    printf("child exited with %d\n", status);
  }
  exit(0);
}
```

Example:

```
$ clang -o forky -Wall forky.c
$ ./forky /bin/echo hello
i am parent of 11522
i am a child process, with pid: 11522
hello
child exited with 0
$
```

Comment: Yup, this is somewhat what I'm trying to do, but yes with rusage and wait4 returning the rum time and other stats, but this is really very helpful! Thanks a ton!